# How to show that any two isomorphic groups have the same number of elements of order $n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $f :G \rightarrow  H$ is an isomorphism such that $|f(x) | = |x|$ for all $x \in G$. Prove that any
two isomorphic groups have the same number of elements of order $n$ for each $n  \in \mathbb{N} $

My attempt: If $|x|=n$ ,then we have $f(x)^n=f(x^n)=1$
But here im confusing that how to  show that any
two isomorphic groups have the same number of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the groups are isomorphic then there is a bijective homomorphism between them.  The bijective part means they have the same number of elements.

They also have the same number of elements of order $n$:  say $x$ has order $n$, then $x^n=e\implies f(x)^n=f(x^n)=f(e)=e\implies $ the order of $f(x)$ divides $n$.  Similarly for $f^{-1}$.  So that the order of $x$ divides the order of $f(x)$.  Thus $x$ and $f(x)$ have the same order.

Comment: The question in the body is a bit different from the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Under an isomorphism $f$, we not only have $x^n=1\implies f(x)^n=1$, but also the reverse direction, i.e., we have $x^n=1\iff f(x)^n=1$. Thus we also have
$$ \begin{align}|x|=n&\iff x^n=1\land \forall  k<n\colon x^k\ne 1\\&\iff  f(x)^n=1\land \forall k<n\colon f(x)^k\ne 1\\&\iff |f(x)|=n.\end{align}$$
Hence $f$ induces a bijection between the set of elements of $G$ of order $n$ and the set of elements of $H$ of order $n$.

---

More generally, an isomorphism bijects corresponding subsets of $G$ and $H$ whenever these subsets can be described in terms of any predicate in the language of first-order logic with equality extended by the group operation. Or in simpler words: isomorphic groups are "the same" for all "group-internal" intents and purposes.

Comment: what is the  meaning of  $\land$? im not getting that symbolics @Hagen Von sir