# what is the meaning of this symbol $ ∧?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have some confusion in symbolics

what is the meaning of this symbol $\land?$

My attempt : I was googling and got the answer given below

[image]

But i didn't  understand the given above  answer

My confusion come from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3908701/557708%5D), pic is given below
[image]

Comment: $\land$ means *and*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression
$$  x^n=1\land \forall  k<n\colon x^k\ne 1 $$

is a logical conjunction of the two terms

$$ x^n = 1$$
and
$$ \forall  k<n\colon x^k\ne 1 .$$

You might write it like this to make it clearer how the symbols are grouped into expressions:
$$  (x^n=1)\land (\forall  k<n\colon x^k\ne 1). $$

This conjunction is true if and only if $x^n=1$ is true and
$\forall  k<n\colon x^k\ne 1$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, $\land$ is the logical AND operator \land.