# what is the meaning of this symbol $ ∨?$

Tags: notation

what is the meaning of this symbol $ ∨?$

My attempt : last time  i was asked this  same problem  with different pattern [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910665/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-symbol-%e2%88%a7)

Earlier  i was thinking that   $ ∨$ similar to union symbolics
But union symbolics is $\cup$

So here im confuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common use of this symbol is as logical operator "or", which connects two statements.

So for two statements $A$ and $B$ the expression $A\vee B$ would read "A or B".

As many other symbols this has other uses too, so it depends on the context. You linked a set-theory related topic.

The other symbol "$\wedge$" is the logical "and".

Edit: Also note that $\cup$ is a set-theoretic operation, while $\vee$ is used for statements. So in two different settings.

You define the set theoretic $\cup$ of two sets $X$ and $Y$ as the set

$X\cup Y:=\{x: x\in X\vee x\in Y\}$

It is a preference of style if you use those symbols, or just write "or", "and" instead.
Outside of the field of mathematical logic, most people avoid these symbols, as they are somewhat unpleasant to read.